# Bad horizontal alignment in tabularray or tabularx

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, tabularx, kerning, tabularray

The second column is not properly aligned to the left in both `tabularry` and `tabularx` environments

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, parskip=half]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[left=27mm, right=27mm, top=25mm, bottom=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[scaled]{helvet} \renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} 

\usepackage{tabularray} 
    \UseTblrLibrary{varwidth}
    \NewTblrEnviron{Tabelle}
    \SetTblrInner[Tabelle]{
        column{1}={leftsep=0pt}, 
        column{2}={rightsep=0pt},
        measure=vbox
    }

\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{Tabelle}{lX}
        10.2020 -- heute & \textbf{Master Materials Science and Engineering} \\ 
        & Technische Universität München, Schwerpunkt Materials in Engineering Applications \\
        02.2019 -- 07.2019 & \textbf{Auslandssemester} \\
        & Otago Polytechnic, Neuseeland \\
        10.2016 -- 09.2020 & {\textbf{Bachelor Maschinenbau} \\
        Ostbayerische Technische Hochschule Regensburg, Schwerpunkt Entwicklung und Konstruktion} \\
        09.2008 -- 07.2016 & {\textbf{Allgemeine Hochschulreife} \\
        Gymnasium Parsberg}
    \end{Tabelle}


    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}lX@{}}
        10.2020 -- heute & \textbf{Master Materials Science and Engineering} \\ 
        & Technische Universität München, Schwerpunkt Materials in Engineering Applications \\
        02.2019 -- 07.2019 & \textbf{Auslandssemester} \\
        & Otago Polytechnic, Neuseeland \\
        10.2016 -- 09.2020 & \textbf{Bachelor Maschinenbau} \\
        & Ostbayerische Technische Hochschule Regensburg, Schwerpunkt Entwicklung und Konstruktion \\
        09.2008 -- 07.2016 & \textbf{Allgemeine Hochschulreife} \\
        & Gymnasium Parsberg
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

EDIT:

The font doesn't seem to be the problem. Here is the same table with the default LaTeX font:
[image]

Comment: I believe that the issue is not with the tables, but rather with the `helvet` font you use. A quick test on plain paragraphs outside the tabular environment shows that they are always misaligned: https://imgur.com/a/wndbZ1l

Maybe your same example should be aligned properly with any other font, can you test if it persists using a monospaced font?

Comment: @MananIntindinichu A different font as well as monospaced ones result in the same alignment

Comment: does it change if you remove `microtype`?

Comment: What you've "discovered" is that in well-designed font families, letters have so-called side bearings -- in general on both the left and the right. What your example further shows is that the (right hand) side bearings can vary considerably across letters. Is this a problem for you?

Comment: @WillieWong it somehow improves the spacing from "Otago", but still not perfect

Comment: @Mico Yeah, it looks really uneven, especialliy in a table. Is there a way to get rid of it?

Comment: I suppose you could set up a routine to (a) measure a letter's left-hand side bearing and (b) put in a negative kern in the amount of that side bearing if the letter occurs at the start of a line. I'm afraid that I have no idea whatsoever how this could be accomplished. What I'm pretty sure of, though, is that the result will look no better than, and quite likely worse than, the current situation. Hence, I'd focus my attention on more important aspects of the document, such as the clarity of the main arguments and the legibility of the tables and figures.

Comment: @Mico thanks for the input. It is supposed to be a CV and I'm happy with everything except the alignment. I find the "B" quite glaring to be honest.